# Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: django, http, cors, polymer, django-rest-framework

I have two separate server,one is **nginx** with **node**,and another one is **django** with **django-rest-framework** for build ding REST API,nginx is responsible for the REST API request,node takes care of client request, also  i use [polymer](http://ttps://www.polymer-project.org) for the frontend .Below are a brief description:

**machine one:**

```
nginx:192.168.239.149:8888 (API listening address) forward to 192.168.239.147:8080

node:192.168.239.149:80 (client listening address)
```

**machine two:**

```
unicorn:192.168.239.147:8080(listening address)
```

The process is when a request comes in,**node server**(`192.168.239.149:80`) responses to return html,in html an AJAX request ask for A**PI server**(`nginx:192.168.239.149:8888 forward to unicorn:192.168.239.147:8080`),and then **unicorn**(`192.168.239.147:8080`) returns the result.

but there is a [CORS](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS)  problem,I read a lot article,and many people met the same questions,I tried many methods,but no help.still error.

**what i get is :**

[image]

[image]

that is:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.239.149:8888/article/. Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

**What i do is :**

**[core-ajax](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-ajax.html)**

```
<core-ajax auto headers='{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*","X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}'  url="http://192.168.239.149:8888/article/" handleAs="json" response="{{response}}"></core-ajax>
```

**nginx:**

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    access_log /tmp/nginx.access.log;
    sendfile on;
    upstream realservers{
                #server 192.168.239.140:8080;
                #server 192.168.239.138:8000;
                server 192.168.239.147:8080;
    }
server {
        listen       8888 default;
        server_name  example.com;
        client_max_body_size 4G;
        keepalive_timeout 5;
        location / {
             add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
                try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @proxy_to_app;
                }
location @proxy_to_app{
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_pass http://realservers;
        }
}
}
```

**node:**

```
app.listen(80, function() {
  console.log('server.js running');
});
```

**unicorn:**

```
return Response(serializer.data,headers={'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
                                                                           'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET',
                                                                           'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Access-Control-Allow-Origin, x-requested-with, content-type',
                                                                           })
```

Because,I have not much experience on CORS,and I want to understand it thoroughly,can anyone point out what i was doing wrong here,I will thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow,so excited,I sovled this all by my self,what i do wrong here is that the request header i sent is not included in the nginx config `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'`

complete nginx config:

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    access_log /tmp/nginx.access.log;
    sendfile on;
    upstream realservers{
                #server 192.168.239.140:8080;
                #server 192.168.239.138:8000;
                server 192.168.239.147:8080;
    }
server {
        listen       8888 default;
        server_name  example.com;
        client_max_body_size 4G;
        keepalive_timeout 5;
        location / {
             add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
             add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
             add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
             add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Access-Control-Allow-Orgin,XMLHttpRequest,Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Mx-ReqToken,X-Requested-With';

                try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @proxy_to_app;
                }
location @proxy_to_app{
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Access-Control-Allow-Orgin,XMLHttpRequest,Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Mx-ReqToken,X-Requested-With';

                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_pass http://realservers;
        }
}
}
```

because my request is :

```
core-ajax auto headers='{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*","X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}'  url="http://192.168.239.149:8888/article/" handleAs="json" response="{{response}}"></core-ajax>
```

i didnt include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `XMLHttpRequest` header into the nginx config `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`,so that is the problem.

I hope its useful to whom has the same problem!

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to include CORS header into request manualy. The browser takes care of it, you just need to allow it on the api server

Comment: yeah,it was  just for testing,i forgot to comment it.